# How to generate video out of images via Wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php, images, videos

I am working on Wordpress plugin which can generate video from sequence of images. I read here that we can use FFMpeg and Imagemagick (or imagick) to implement this trick. But, FFMpeg is hardly supported on shared hosting. So, this option is ruled out.

I started working on Imagemagick. But, I was informed here that both of the above options cannot be used for Wordpress. So, is there any feasible option for developing a video file out of images for Wordpress???

I am storing sequence of images in /images folder and want to develop and video out of these images.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This question is more to do with general PHP, rather than WordPress, it would be better placed on perhaps stack overflow or the programmers exchange

Comment: Besides, what you're trying to do is likely to upset shared hosters regardless because generating video is not cheap from a computational resource standpoint, and most rules on a shared host are because there isn't much in the way of resources to begin with. You would be best carting your images off to a service that would do the job for you

Comment: See the same, answered question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9946343/299509

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is likely to upset shared hosters regardless because generating video is not cheap from a computational resource standpoint, and most rules on a shared host are because there isn't much in the way of resources to begin with. You would be best carting your images off to a service that would do the job for you.

Trying to duplicate the work of ffmpeg etc in PHP will likely exceed the execution timeout, so you're not going anywhere where shared hosts are concerned. You may be able to get away with GIFs, and keep ffmpeg support for those on a VPS

Comment: This is sad to know. Thanks for the information friend. So, finally, no means to implement it on shared hosting, right???

Comment: I just checked out "ImageMagick Engine" plugin for Wordpress which runs well on my shared hosting. The plugin is using Imagemagick php module. So, cant this be used to generate a video file? Please reply.

Comment: Image Magick isnt always available, and as the title suggests, it's intended for images. That plugin has nothing at all to do with video as the plugins description says. It simply replaces the calls to the GD image library with ones to the rival ImageMagick library